# Getting rid of the absolute value in the resolution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, partial-fractions

I have this differential equation as an exercise:

> $y' = y^2 - uy$, where u is a real parameter.

While trying to resolve it, I got to a point where I have:

> $|\frac{y-u}{y}| = Ce^{ux}$, where $C$ is a positive real number.

Can I discard the absolute value if I extend the domain of $C$ to any non-zero real number? Am I leaving some solutions out by doing so?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  The solution you have is equivalent to $\frac{y-u}{y} =Ce^{ux}$ where $C$ is an arbitrary nonzero real number.

Comment: But I have a bit of an issue with that. Imagine that it was $|y| = Cx^2$, C>0. Then, according to what you said, we would have $y = Cx^2$, C =/=0. But wouldn't we be leaving out the function $y(x) = x^2$ when x is negative and $y(x) = -x^2$ when x is positive?

Comment: Yes, but in this case because the right-hand side of the expression is always nonzero, and because we are (presumably) looking for a continuous function, you don't have to worry about the possibility of a function that switches signs.

Comment: Oh you are sooo right. You just cleared a heavy fog in my mind with your last comment! Thanks a lot